# It was a long, long drop -- meaning of "drop" here

Tags: meaning

*He didn't want her watching him as he jumped off. So long as no one was watching he would be able to say afterwards that he had slipped and fallen by accident. He peered over the side of the ship. **It was a long, long drop.***

Source: Roald Dahl: Dip in the Pool

I do not fully understand the last sentence of my excerpt. None of the meanings of the word "drop" make sense to me here. Given the context (the man is preparing to jump off the ship) the only explanation is that the sentence describes the protagonist's assessment regarding the height from the side of the ship to the surface of the sea. Am I right?

Answer (score 6):

That's correct. Cambridge describes drop, as a noun, to be:

> the distance from one thing to something lower

Thus, it is a long, long distance from the side of the ship to the surface of the sea.

Comment: "If I would fall, the **drop** will take a **long** time."

Comment: @Martijn, this is not using the word drop in the same way as it's used in the question.  you're using drop to mean "descent" or "fall," not "distance."  the narrator in _dip in the pool_ is saying "it was a long, long [distance]" -- even before he jumped -- not, "it was a long, long [fall]" -- he hasn't fallen yet!

Comment: second, @Martijn, your sentence is grammatically incorrect.  it should be, "if i would fall, the drop _would_ take a long time."  or better yet, "if i were to fall, the drop would take a long time."

Comment: My bad, typed it in a rush. I can't edit the comment anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the same distance as *rise*, but with the connotation of being measured from the top down, where rise is always from the bottom up. (See also: height, depth, lift, climb, fall... all vertical measurements, but with different connotations.)

So you measure the drop of a waterfall, the drop of a purse (from the shoulder of the person carrying it to the top of the purse), or the drop from one mechanical part to another where the top one is at a fixed height and the bottom one is adjustable.